# WPF subwindow getting closed if i click the button on it

Tags: c#, wpf

```
if (VendorSettingWondow == null)
{
    VendorSettingWondow = new VendorSettingWindow();
    VendorSettingWondow.Top = this.Top;
    VendorSettingWondow.Left = this.Left + this.Width/2;
    //VendorSettingWondow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    VendorSettingWondow.injdf.Text = filename; // setting file name
    VendorSettingWondow.inJDFVendorInfo.ItemsSource = inJDFVendors;
   // VendorSettingWondow.inJDFVendorInfo.ItemsSource = vendorList.Vendors;
    VendorSettingWondow.DBVendorList.ItemsSource = DBvendorList.Vendors;
    VendorSettingWondow.ShowDialog();
}
```

I am creating a subwindow if some condition is satisfied in the main window like above. There are two buttons in my sub window. When i click the button the sub window is getting closed. I am using `ShowDialog()` because I want to control to be transferred from main window to sub window when the subwindow is created

Comment: Take a look at the Click event handlers attached to the buttons. Is there any code there? If so, could you post it here?

Comment: What is the question? Do you describe the desired behaviour and don't know how to implement that? Or do you want to stop the button from closing the form?

Comment: yes i want the button to stop from closing the form. because  the buttons are meant  for some other task

Comment: The event handler is a simple button click event which is used to add or delete some data. but The issue is by using showDefault() my sub window is automatically getting closed when i press any button.

Comment: You have to show us the code. Either you set DialogResult somewhere in the button handler or the property Cancel of the button is set to true.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `IsCancel` property of the Button. If it is set to `true`, set it to `false` to prevent the button from closing the dialog.